# get all weeks of current month in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get all weeks of current month in c# like

```
1.3.2000 Monday 
2.3.2000 Tuesday 
.
.
.
30.3.2000 Friday
```

can you please help me in this

Comment: Do you mean you want to get a name of the weekday for each date? This is what your example is showing.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Carefully and thorougly study [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) and its members.

Comment: `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)` to get number of the days in month; `date.ToString("d.M.yyyy dddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to represent the `date` in the required format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the days of the current month in mentioned format with name of the week-day, this code will suffice:

```
using System; 

public class Program 
{ 
 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
       int year = 2020;
       int month = 3;
       DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
       DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
      while (startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
       startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
      for (DateTime result = startDate; result < endDate; result = result.AddDays(1))
       Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(" dd.MM.yyyy dddd"));
       Console.ReadLine(); 
  } 
}
```

[image: Output: all the days of the current month]

To get only particular date & day(like Mondays) from each week/all the weeks in current month in mentioned format, this code will suffice:

```
using System; 

public class Program 
{ 
 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      int year = 2020;
      int month = 3;
      DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
      DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
    while (startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
      startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    for (DateTime result = startDate; result < endDate; result = result.AddDays(7))
      Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(" dd.MM.yyyy dddd"));
      Console.ReadLine();

   } 
}
```

[image: Output: Mondays from all the weeks in current month]